# How to show WordPress custom post type entries in a feed?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type called article. I can create articles and everything is working fine. However, I have questions on the feeds.

1) How do I see the latest articles I created in a feed?

2) How do I see all the blog posts and articles all in one feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to your functions.php file

```
function myfeed_request($qv) 
{
   if (isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
   {
     $qv['post_type'] = get_post_types($args = array(
                'public'   => true,
                '_builtin' => false
     ));
     array_push($qv['post_type'],'post');
     return $qv;
   }
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

Check out this page [here](http://www.ballyhooblog.com/add-custom-post-types-wordpress-main-feed/) for more details

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out..I was able to solve it though through playing with the url. Similar to this //mywebsite/feed?post_type=article&genre=comedy

Comment: This url solution works only on IIS and Apache, I wonder why it does not work on my nginx machine... :(

Comment: You solution does not work for me :( Does it have to do with the webserver being used. Mine is nginx.

Comment: I found out the reason why it is not working. I switched to Apache and now it works..thanks!